# How do I use express.json() and set headers (res.setHeader) simultaneously?

Tags: json, express, post, body-parser

I am trying to view the body of a POST request and also set some headers. Specifically, I need to allow localhost -> localhost communication, which means adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` as a header.

My code so far is:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.sendStatus(200);
  next();
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.name)
  res.end();
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

When I run the server I get `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

How can I combine both app.use()s?

I've tried changing the order of the calls but that doesn't work.

Comment: The issue is not in the code you shared. You are setting a header somewhere after sending the body. There's no code here that sends a body.

Comment: Hi @Evert, thanks for the quick reply! I'm sending a POST request via a different method (axios), but I have to change the response headers (I think?) so that I can send from http:localhost to http:localhost. That works, but when I try to incorporate express.json() in order to read the body of the POST request, that's when it fails.

Comment: Adding `express.json()` can not be the cause of the error you shared. the error is related to the *response* body.

Comment: Side comment: you never need to list `Origin` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way after I posted the question, so I'm sharing it here for anyone else:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.use(function( req, res, next ) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type"
  );
  res.sendStatus(200);
  let data = "";
  req.on("data", function( chunk ) {
    data += chunk;
    console.log(data);
    next();
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```